# Creating new services other than the predefined ones using HM-10 BLE module

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, uuid, hm-10

I'm working on a BLE project (bike tracker) using HM-10 module and i need to send over BLE some data (speed, location, time, date, battery level). I did some research and I found out that i can use these 3 services to send the data :

1. Location and Navigation service (0x1819)
2. Current Time service (0x1805)
3. Battery service (0x180F)
   The main problem is i'm unaible to create a new service other than the predefined ones in the HM-10 module.
   i tried to create a new service using "AT+UUID" but it only changes the UUID of the existing custom service.
   I assume that it's impossible because there's no AT command in the datasheet to create a service.
   Is there a way to create a new service with this module ?
   if not, can i send the data (speed, location, time, date, battery level) using only one service so i can print them all at once in real time on the phone app (nRF connect/ BLE scanner)?
   Any suggestion of another BLE module that works with AT commands and can create new services will help.

Comment: I afraid you can not do what you need with HM-10 without re-flashing custom firmware. The best solution for you is to swithc to ESP32.

Comment: I believe your HM-10 implements a UART service that would allow you to send and receive whatever you want. So yes, it is possible to send the data using only one service. It's just a question on how to represent the data so you can extract the individual values after receiving them in your app

Comment: i'm stuck with the HM-10 module and i have no idea how to re-flash it's firmware so i think i have no other choice but to use the available custom service (UART service), i'll work on extracting the data values after the reception. Thanks for the help !